# Solve the equation of degree 4

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation $(1+c)^3(c-1)=3$.

I don't know how to solve it. Can anyone show a solution?

Comment: **Hint:** Simplify and write it as $(c+2) \left(c^3-2\right)= 0$.

Comment: Given $(1+c)^3(c-1)=3$

Expand

$$ c^4 + 2c^3 - 2c -4 = 0$$

Try using the rational root theorem ($-2,-1,1,2..$)

Trying those we get c = -2 as a root so (c+2) is a factor , try factoring using polynomial division or any preferred method..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expand it out you get $c^4+2 c^3-2 c-4 = 0$.  You can use the rational root theorem to find a factor $c+2$ and factor it as $(c+2)(c^3-2)=0$